# Wordpress Html5 Blank not reading style.css

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm having a little problem. Yesterday I was trying to put a favicon and added this (it was a bit different because it had the right name and link to the favicon)
`<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>` in my header.php after `<link rel='stylesheet' id='normalize-css'  href='http://crvlh.com/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/normalize.css?ver=1.0' media='all' />
  <link rel='stylesheet' id='html5blank-css'  href='http://crvlh.com/wp-content/themes/html5blank-stable/style.css?ver=1.0' media='all' />` and since them (even after deleting the favicon links) its not reading my style.css. This is what i see when i inspect my head links [image] Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at your site and there's a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) before `href` when you try to call your stylesheet. Whatever you're using to edit the text inserts a non-breaking space when you type (or accidentally type) two spaces. This commonly happens in rich text editors, and they're difficult to spot when rendered because they look like regular spaces. When the browser tries to parse the string, it doesn't read `&nbsp;href` as a valid attribute and so doesn't know that there's actually a linked resource.

Comment: thanks man! can believe i spend all morning struggling with this just because of a space ahah. have a nice weekend!